# Symfony service's tags exception (YAML)

Tags: symfony, yaml

This gives exception (Tags must be array, check YAML syntax):

```
services:
    application.presentation.twig.extension.nullableDateTime:
        class: AppBundle\Application\Presentation\Twig\Extension\NullableDateTime
        tags: [twig.extension]
```

This does not:

```
services:
    application.presentation.twig.extension.nullableDateTime:
        class: AppBundle\Application\Presentation\Twig\Extension\NullableDateTime
        tags:
            - {name: twig.extension}
```

Why is that? The Symfony docs says to use `[]` for tags.
I have used the `{}` syntax somewhere else, maybe only one syntax is accepted?

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html

Comment: Using brackets was introduced in 3.3.  You are using an older version of Symfony. https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/service_container/tags.html

Comment: More details: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#adding-additional-attributes-on-tags